# Drools timer based rule session always resides in memory and cause memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, drools

I'm a newbie to Drools. I want to delay 5s after I fired the rule (and just for one time). So, I use timer(int:5s) to do that. But I found that after the rule executed, my console application will never be terminated and its javaw.exe process still exist in my task manager. The only one way is to call ksession.dispose(). But it's not acceptable because it's hard to find this ksession in our clustering architect.

So, is there any way to make the ksession automatically disposed after the rule executed?

Here are my simple test case:

1. main class

   ```
   public class App {
       public static void main( String[] args ) {
           System.out.println("Started...");       

           KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
           kbuilder.add(new ClassPathResource("Timer.drl", App.class), ResourceType.DRL); 
           KnowledgeBase kbase = kbuilder.newKnowledgeBase();
           StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();        
           ksession.fireAllRules();        

           System.out.println("Ended");
       }
   }
   ```
2. drl file

   ```
   package myDrools.TimerTest1

   rule "Your First Rule"

   timer(int:5s)

   when
       eval(true)
   then
       System.out.println("Finished");
   end
   ```

   The output will be:

   ```
   Started...
   Ended
   Finished
   ```

But my console application will never be terminated. Is there something wrong? I tested it both in Drools 5.6.0 Final and 6.4.0 Final. However, both of them has the same issue. I think the ksession should be disposed since timer(int:5s) is not an interval timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timers run in parallel to the thread hosting the session and keep the session alive. In a way, they are meant to be used in sessions running indeterminate, i.e., not started calling fireAllRules.

The following scenario should give you a clean shutdown:

```
rule  "Your First Rule"
  timer( int:5s )
when
then
  System.out.println("Finished");
  drools.halt();
end
```

And your session is started like this:

```
kieSession.fireUntilHalt();
System.out.println( "return from fireUntilHalt" );
kieSession.dispose();
```

**Edit**

If you need to call halt in any case you can add another rule with the negated condition which calls halt right away.

```
rule "stop if not met"
when
    // negated condition X
then
    drools.halt();
end
```

Hint: The negated condition X is *not* `not X`!

Comment: Hi laune,

Thanks for you reply. There is a problem for this solution. If the when part is not true, drools.halt() will not be hit. So, is there something like finally clause to make sure the drools.halt() could be run?

Comment: I have a not very nice solution which is to use do[abc] then... then[abc]

Comment: Probably an unconditional rule with timer(int:6s) (6=5+1) calling halt would be the simplest solution :-)

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions:) Yes, 6s is ok for most cases. But it's based on the real rule can be executed within 1s. So, I think that add a do and two then clause will make sure the drools.halt() will run and it's more acceptable for our end user to edit it. Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

Based on laune's great answer, I modified my drl file to make sure the drools.halt() will always be hit. (Note: v6.4.0 Final is OK. But v5.6.0 Final will throw exception for do clause)

```
dialect "mvel"
rule "Hello World"
timer(int:5s)
when
    m : Message()
    if ( m.status == Message.HELLO)
    do[hello]
then
    System.out.println( "other status" );
    drools.halt();
then[hello]
    System.out.println( "Hello!" );
    drools.halt();
```

end